# how to print the textboxes present in div tag with position=relative using printer in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:Image id="cheque_image" runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" style="position:absolute;z-index:1;height:320px;width:695px;margin-top:20px;"></asp:Image>
<div id="div_ToPrint"  style="position:relative;z-index:10;">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_date" Width="140" placeholder="Date" ></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="x_date" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="y_date" runat="server" />
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_payee_name"  placeholder="Payee Name" Width="450" ></asp:TextBox>  
      <asp:HiddenField ID="x_payee_name" runat="server" />
      <asp:HiddenField ID="y_payee_name" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Here there is a `div` tag which has `style` like `position: relative` from which I have to print textboxes using printer